# How to avoid table scrollable contents from being visible behind as shown in the pic?

Tags: html, css, html-table, styles

[image]

Iam trying to make the tbody scrollable which iam able to attain by fixing height and overflow, but when i scroll, the content of the tbody overlap the table as shown. What am i missing? Any help would be useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your css? You made fixed height and overflow on parent div element, not on tbody of the table.

Comment: @MaksimL I tried adding the same to tbody but it doesnt seem to work. Hence i added it to the parent div. It works there, but after making th as static, when i scroll the tbody, it overflow in the background as shown. I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

```
.card-body          { overflow-y: auto; height: 440px; } 
.card-body thead th { position: sticky; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an alternative approach. I removed padding for .card-body and instead used margin. Now the contents do not overflow.

.card-body {padding:0px;margin:15px;}